# how to see process status with full details

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, process, ksh

I run the script - **my_script.ksh** as process with 5 long arguments

on my solaris/linux machine ( example 1 ) ,

Later I verify the process by

```
 ps -ef | grep  my_script.ksh
```

I don't understand way I not get the all arguments from **ps -ef** ? , ( see example 2 )

or maybe ps command have limitation to display a long line ? , 
or maybe need to write the ps command with some flags that will
enable to display all arguments ?

what need to do in order see all arguments from **ps -ef** command ?

**Example 1** ( run **my_script.ksh** with the relevant arguments )

```
           #  ( /tmp/my_script.ksh PATH1=/usr/lib/efcode/sparcv9/efdaemon PATH2=/etc/opt/VO/share/conf/nnmet/mib/Fore-pre802dot1Q-VLAN-MIB.mib -scan-files -ignore-simbolic-links -give-full-file-details ) &
 [1]     18942
```

**Example 2** ( verify script proccess , but can't see all arguments ? )

```
       # ps -ef | grep my_script.ksh 
root 18942 11889   0 13:22:20 pts/1       0:00 /bin/ksh /tmp/my_script.ksh PATH1=/usr/lib/efcode/sparcv9/efdaemon PATH2=/etc/o
```

Comment: Try `ps -ef` without `grep` and try `ps -ef | less -+S`.

Comment: I get the same results with ps -ef | less -+S -:(

Comment: @Khaled - Maybe need to transfer my question to stack-overflow ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Solaris, try using `/usr/ucb/ps -auxwww | grep my_script.sh` instead. This will show the full command line and arguments of the process.
For Linux, simply use `ps aux`.

Also try experimenting with forcing certain fields only to be displayed by `ps`, 
e.g. `ps -ao comm,args` will display the command and its arguments.

A bit of time spent in `man ps` should get you on the right track.

Comment: GREAT ITS WORKS -:) -:) -:) thx so mutch

Comment: What the ???  Why no mentioning of the Solaris `pargs` command. The other answer below should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/ucb/ps` is being deprecated and no more installed by default in current Solaris releases.

`ps -ao comm,args` will suffer the same issue, i.e. command line truncated to 80 characters by design.

Here is a supported alternative solution:

```
pargs $(pgrep my_script.sh)
```